# How to Distinguish the 22 Variables in the Stacked Bar Graph?

Tags: python, pandas, colors, visualization, plotly

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 75 samples (rows) and measures of 22 different human cell types (columns), like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py
import cufflinks as cf

cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True, theme='ggplot')

#pandas dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
np.random.rand(75, 22), columns=    
['B cells naive','B cells memory','Plasma cells','T cells CD8','T cells CD4 naive','T cells CD4 memory resting','T cells CD4 memory activated','T cells follicular helper','T cells regulatory (Tregs)','T cells gamma delta','NK cells resting','NK cells activated','Monocytes','Macrophages M0','Macrophages M1','Macrophages M2','Dendritic cells resting','Dendritic cells activated','Mast cells resting','Mast cells activated','Eosinophils','Neutrophils']
)

df.iplot(kind="bar", barmode="stack")
```

I want to visualize how much of each of the 22 cell types present in the 75 samples.  So I thought to use a stacked bar graph where each bar represent a sample and the stacks show the estimated number of each cell type found in the sample.  Here is the graph generated using Plotly:
[image: Plotly Playground 2016-10-30 21-05-37.png]

**Problem:** the cell types represented in the stacked bar graph do not have unique and distingishable color.  For example, there are three cell types have the the same color (red) and this makes the graph pointless because we can not visualize the frequency of each cell types per sample.

**Question:** what are some possible ways to distinguish the cell types for each sample? ... Any ideas what sets of colors and/or patterns could be used to solve this problem?

Do you think there are other ways to visualize, other than a stacked bar graph?

Thanks!

Comment: I can see only 6 dominant colours. Plot only these. Data visualization is an art and a science. This article might help: http://iedf.in/index.php/blog/item/storytelling-with-data

Comment: just a few thoughts, maybe you could sort the contributions in each sample so that the largest cell type contributions are on the bottom (or top) of each bar.  next, I don't think you'll get 22 colors that are distinguishable, maybe just label the cell types with numbers and instead of coloring the bars, label the segments with numbers.

Comment: You do not want a single bar chart unless you want to show how messy the data and relationships are. There will just be too much for the observer to try and unpack at a glance, which defeats the purpose of having a chart in the first place. I would recommend using a heatmap instead. You could have the samples along one axis, and the cells on the other. You could then group the cells by type and maybe order the samples by similarity. 

https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/#heatmap-with-categorical-axis-labels

Comment: I should have asked this first but... what story are you trying to tell to the audience with the graphic? Or is this the case of looking for the story via a chart?

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  @Karnage I am trying to understand the data from different angles using graphs.  At the same time I was encouraged to  use a stack bar graph for that manner since it helps to visualize the frequency of each cell type across all the samples (holistic view of the data)

Comment: If it is for your own analysis then you have hundreds of options and no need to cram lots of data into a single representation. No reason you couldnt peruse 22 individual bar charts, one for each cell type. Maybe from there you could investigate combinations of cell types in a matrix of scatterplots? Have a look into the [scatter_matrix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) .
I would also recommend you look into Principle Component Analysis (PCA) as for dimensionality reduction. (These 75 samples differ along 22 dimensions.)